# IPtables not allowing yum in centos 7

Tags: iptables, yum

I have set DROP as default rule for all in my centos 7 system and allow only following rules.

```
#Allow web server ports
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

When I run `yum update`. Error occured. When I disabled iptables `yum update` work successfully. Is yum use some port other than 80. What rule I should add to allow `yum update` to run successfully.

Answer (score 3):

i'd write these

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

Dont forget to open for the DNS as well

iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT  -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT

and a line to accept packets from outbound connections

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

Comment: That's what i said, you should open the DNS ports as well, i'll add them

Comment: New Issue fa996-prestodelta.xml.gz: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')

Comment: i could'n see the full iptables, but i assume you blocking all the in, i'm adding 1 line for it

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT